# Google Search Results in text format

Tags: google-search

I am searching for all pdfs from a specific site using the Google Dork "`site:resosir.com filetype:pdf`". How can I make a text file with all pdf links from the search result, one in each line?

### Attempt:

I tried [Goosh](http://goosh.org/) and [Googler](https://github.com/jarun/googler), but it shows the title and brief description of the results as well, which I don't want. I wan't only the urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I would do:

1. click on each result;
2. save all tabs as favorites on a specific folder/group;
3. export your favorites;
4. take the favorites export file and edit it to have only the folder/group you want.